# Can not install @0x/asset-swapper with NPM / Yarn. Ends up in error "Error: spawn cargo ENOENT"

Tags: 0x

When trying to install asset-swapper repo, either via NPM or Yarn, I end up on:

"response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/0xProject/fast-abi/releases/download/0.0.2/node-v83-win32-x64.tar.gzneon ERR! spawn cargo ENOENT

Error: spawn cargo ENOENT"

Sadly, the error does not lie and there is nothing on the link really. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

We unfortunately don't support Windows at this stage, so a fix is not possible. You can find the tar.gz file for Linux and Mac though, and running your install with either of these should work as expected.

Comment: Can you please further clarify? I tried installing on ubuntu 20.06 with NPM and it says the very same. Should I install by some other way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you might need to install Rust and/or use Node 12.